# Django AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'

Tags: python, django, wsgi

When deploying my `djangocms` project I keep getting this `AttributeError`. On my local machine everything runs smoothly in the pycharm testserver.

On my VPS i have also setup a virtualenv and installed all the requirements
I use python 3.6 and os is ubunto 16.04.

Please advice which possible checks I can take to resolve this issue.

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 1224:tid 140015438874368]  mod_wsgi (pid=1224): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/geocms/geocms/wsgi.py'.

[wsgi:error] [pid 1224:tid 140015438874368] [Traceback (most recent call last):

[wsgi:error] [pid 1224:tid 140015438874368] File "/var/www/html/geocms/geocms_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 393, in urlconf_module

[wsgi:error] [pid 1224:tid 140015438874368]      return self._urlconf_module

[wsgi:error] [pid 1224:tid 140015438874368]  AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'
```